# How to invoke an Ethereum function from a web server?

Tags: solidity

I have a hardware device that detects events I would like to save in the Ethereum blockchain.

So my idea is that the hardware device will call an API function in my web application (C#, node, PHP, etc.), and the web application will call using web3.js a function in my Ethereum smart contract. Everything should be done automatically without human intervention.

My solidity program is this one:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

contract Logs {

  struct Log {
    string user;
    uint deviceId;
    uint time;
  }

  Log[] logsList;

  function writeLog(string _user, uint _deviceId) external {
    logsList.push(Log(_user, _deviceId, now));
  }
}
```

I tested using testrpc and Metamask and works fine.

But I'm wondering:

1. How to call the writeLog function from the backend of my web application? I'm assuming that the contract has ether enough to pay for the gas.
2. How can I be sure that the call is done only by my backend? I don't want a malicious user to call directly the function and consume all the ether of the contract

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use web3.py library to invoke contract without user interaction. Using web3.py can estimate  gas and get the gas price for a client.

I hope contract owner(you) will pay gas for writeLog() if so you need to change little bit your implementation.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

contract Logs {

  struct Log {
    string user;
    uint deviceId;
    uint time;
  }

  Log[] logsList;
  address contractOwner;
  function Logs(){
      contractOwner = msg.sender;
  }
  function writeLog(string _user, uint _deviceId) onlyContractOwner external {
    logsList.push(Log(_user, _deviceId, now));
  }
  modifier onlyContractOwner() {
    require(msg.sender == contractOwner);
    _;
  }
}
```

Adding `onlyContractOwner` modifier, to writeLog function, only contract owner will save log's. For more details click below links:

[Web3.py Doc](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

[Web3.js Doc](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/)